# How to trigger DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged if I select the same option(the same index)?

Tags: c#, html, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

As title, in C#, I was wondering that if I selected the same index in a dropdownlist, how could I trigger the function (`OnSelectedIndexChanged`)?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Silver"> Silver </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="DarkGray"> Dark Gray </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Khaki"> Khaki </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="DarkKhaki"> Dark Khaki </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

There is a scenario as below following:
I selected "White" at first, and it triggered `ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged` successfully.

Then as need I selected "White" again, how could I trigger the function `ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged` again?

Comment: Can we get a snippet?

Comment: You meant the ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged snippet?